# How to extract object keys

Tags: javascript

I have this following object:

```js
{
  12232: [],
  34232: [],
  23435: []
}
```

I want to extract the keys from this object to show them as labels in my React frontend. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON Object. JSON is a text format. What you have there is an object literal, and you can use [`Object.keys(theObject)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of keys.

Comment: "JavaScript Object Notation Object."  If there's something wrong with this, I don't see it.  I would say `{ foo: 'bar' }` is a JSO but not a JSON, while `{ "foo": "bar" }` is both.

Comment: @GirkovArpa OP talks about JSON Objects, which makes no sense. It's also not JSON, it's just an object literal.

Comment: @ChrisG https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: @GirkovArpa "JSO" is not an acronym in widespread use. And there are no "JSON objects" - `a = { "foo": "bar" }` is an object literal in code. There is no special name for that or difference with `a = { foo: "bar" }`. If it's *text*, then `{ "foo": "bar" }` is JSON but it's not JS code.

Comment: @user2426691 No, sorry, that's actually the best example of why w3schools is bad and shouldn't be used, much less linked to from this website. Please remove the comment. See also here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Comment: @user2426691 W3 schools is notoriously misleading and plain wrong in many cases, this one included.

Comment: @ChrisG Ok thanks for the heads up, i'll delete the entire question while I'm at it as it is a duplicate

Comment: Sorry guys, it says I can't delete because others have invested time and effort answering

Comment: @VLAZ The following page uses the term "JSON objects": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON I'm not denying OP misused the term.  But I do think it's a legitimate term.  Particularly since JSON, taken literally, refers to the syntax.  Hence the "Object" in "JSON Object".

Answer (score 1):

The method `Object.keys()` allows you to loop over the keys of an object.
You should be able to use it in order to get what you want.

[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1):

Use JS built-in `Object.keys()` for that.

```js
const myObject = {
  12232: [],
  34232: [],
  23435: []
};


const keys = Object.keys(myObject);

keys.forEach(key => {
  console.log(key);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use

```
  obj = { abc: "1",  def: "2" }
  console.log(Object.keys(obj))
```

It will log `["abc", "def"]`. Then you can map through this array and display the values as required.

[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.keys` to extract the keys out of your object.

You could check the docs of `Object.keys` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
const obj = {
 12232 : [],
 34232 : [],
 23435: []
}

Object.keys(obj); // returns ['12232', '34232', '23435'];
```